# How can I reproduce Ruby's Array.compact() in C without using any library?

Tags: c

I need to this function in C that takes a tab of strings and its length as parameters. It's supposed to erase empty tab blocks (just like Ruby's Array.compact) and return the new tab's size :

```
int     strtab_compact(char **tab, int length)
{
    ...
}
```

for example if I have :

```
tab[0] = "foo";
tab[1] = 0; // nul
tab[2] = "bar";
tab[3] = 0;
tab[4] = "baz";
i = strtab_compact(tab, 5) // tab should = ["foo"]["bar"]["baz"] and i = 3
```

I am just starting C (it's my second week) and I have the following piece of code but I'm totally stuck :

```
int strtab_compact(char **tab, int length)
{
    int i;
    int index;

    iterations = 0;
    i = 0;
    // First iteration to get how many valid entries we've got
    while (i < length)
    {
        if (tab[i])
            index++;
        i++;
    }
    // I'll need a second iteration to reorganize the tab and I have no idea how to delete the remaining slots
    i = 0;
    while (...)
    {
        ...
    }
    return (index);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to *delete* the "slots"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two iterations, but you need two iterator indices: `i` iterates over the array and `index` advances only when you find a non-null string. The length of the compact array is then the value of `index` after iteration:

```
int strtab_compact(char **tab, int length)
{
    int index = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (tab[i]) tab[index++] = tab[i];
    }

    return index;
}
```

Because you delete only `NULL` entries, you don't have to worry about freeing memory for the deleted strings, if they are allocated on the heap. (In your example they aren't. I just wanted to mention that you have to take care what happens to the elements you delete, because access to them will be lost after compacting.)

Comment: If you really want to shrink down the size of the array after *compacting* non null entries then you can call `*tab = realloc(*tab,index)`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Restricting the caller to using a particular kind of memory is usually a horrible idea. Better off letting the caller decide...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That aside, I'm sure you're aware that the `foo = realloc(foo, ...);` pattern is always an error.

Comment: Both remarks correct, I know. For the first it may be too advanced for a beginner to understand why. For the second, I answered a little bit too fast (@Ki realloc may fail even when shrinking),  need some more success test like `{ char *newPtr = realloc(*tab,index); if (newPtr) *tab=newPtr; }`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès n this question, `*tab` points into a string literal. That's not a suitable argument for `realloc`...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Also, index would need some factor, unless you are on an architecture with char-sized pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
int strtab_compact(char **tab, int length){
    int i, index;

    for(index = i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        if(tab[i] != NULL)
            tab[index++] = tab[i];
    }
    for(i = index; i < length; ++i)
        tab[i] = NULL;

    return index;
}
```